# daterangepicker not working in cloned div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone a div, which works fine, but in that div there is a daterangepicker element which does not work in the cloned div. I tried a lot of ways, but it is simply not working. Can anyone help ?

```
var $div = $('div[id^="divSession"]:last');
var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
var $divSession = $div.clone().prop('id', 'divSession' + num ).appendTo('#tabbed3_content');

$("#location_daterange_").daterangepicker({drops: 'up', opens: 'left', timePicker: true, timePicker24Hour: true, autoUpdateInput: false, locale: {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'},})
$("#location_daterange_").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {$(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));});
$("#location_daterange_").on('cancel.daterangepicker', function() {$(this).val('');});
```

The cloning works, but when clicking the daterangepicker its not working. The following is the hard coded daterangepicker element which opens fine.

```
<input type="text" id="location_daterange_" class="location_daterange[]" name="location_daterange[]" value="" autocomplete="off" role="presentation">
<script>
    $("#location_daterange_").daterangepicker({drops: 'up', opens: 'left', timePicker: true, timePicker24Hour: true, autoUpdateInput: false, locale: {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'}, })
    $("#location_daterange_").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {$(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));});
    $("#location_daterange_").on('cancel.daterangepicker', function() {$(this).val('');});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While cloning you need to bind an event to the `daterangepicker` like below:

```
$(document).on('datepicker-change', '#location_daterange_' , function() {
     //code here ....
});
```